# How to implement a custom loss function with canned estimators in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow.

*Question*: How can I add a custom loss function to a canned estimator like `DNNLinearCombinedRegressor`?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a `loss_fn` argument to pass in to `DNNLinearCombinedRegressor`. But it looks straightforward to define any custom estimator:

A good reference is the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py#L845) for `DNNLinearCombinedRegressor`.

I believe you need following steps:

1. define a custom `loss_fn` (what ever you like)
2. define or use a `RegressionHead` that [uses](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/head/regression_head.py#L114) the custom `loss_fn` defined above.
3. [pass](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py#L1008) the custom `head` to your own `Regressor`. Of course, you might need to copy/build your own `model_fn` as well.